# execl() not starting a new program, C++

Tags: c++, linux

I'm working on a graph coloring problem in C++ for my uni. I'm quite new to C, C++ and Linux. I wrote a function that's supposed to create a .svg file using graphviz and display it using eye of gnome. My idea was to fork my program, execute a graphviz command, and after it finishes, execute an eog command. The code is:

```
int pid, status;
    if ((pid = fork()) == -1) {
        std::cerr<<"fork error"<<std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    if (pid == 0) {
        execl("/usr/bin/dot", "dot", "-Tsvg", "temp.dot", "-o", "graph.svg", NULL);
        std::cerr<<"exec error"<<std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    wait(&status);
    if (status != 1) {
        execl("/usr/bin/eog", "eog", "graph.svg", NULL);
        std::cerr<<"exec error"<<std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
```

If I'm understanding correctly, the first argument of execl is the path to the command, which I got typing `which dot` and `which eog`. Then, we're inputing command line arguments, followed by NULL. If I remove this block of code from my program and just type these 2 commands into the terminal, everything works fine.

After running the code, the terminal displayed two "exec error" messages, which means two things:

1. Both execl() commands failed, and I have no idea why.
2. If the first exec failed, then the child process should return 1, so the "status" variable should be equal to 1, so the second exec shouldn't even be executed. I think I don't understand something, can you help? :D

Comment: There are two problems here. The execution problem, and correctly checking the exit status. To investigate the execution problem your first order of business is to see what `errno` says about it. Do you know what `errno` is, and how to use it? Then, review the manual page for the `wait()` system call, which will explain how to correctly use the return value from `wait()` (no, it is not, exactly, the process's exit status). Did you read `wait()`'s manual page?

Comment: @EricPostpischil the C library is part of the C++ standard.

Comment: to automate such command line i'd use a bash script. using `fork` in C++ is rather heay-weight for this task

Comment: Prepend the binary run with `strace` and see what happens around the call.

Comment: @NoleKsum taken literally your comment is wrong. Anyhow, the question is clearly about C++ not about C, hence the C tag is offtopic

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number https://eel.is/c++draft/library.c

Comment: @NoleKsum: (a) `fork`, `execl`, and `wait` are not part of the standard C library. (b) Even if they were, where C++ incorporates parts of C by reference, the resulting specification is part of the C++ standard, and questions about it are C++ questions unless they specifically involve some interpretation of the wording of the C standard. (c) There is nothing about this question that involves any interpretation of the C standard.

Comment: @NoleKsum and? Standard says "The C++ standard library also makes available the facilities of the C standard library, suitably adjusted to ensure static type safety." you say "the C library is part of the C++ standard". When taken literally thats two very different statements. Anyhow, there is no point in discussing this for every question about C++. C++ questions should be tagged with C++, don't you think so?

Answer (score -1):

```
int main() 
{
    int pid, status;
    if ((pid = fork()) == -1) {
        std::cerr<<"fork error"<<std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    if (pid == 0) {
        execl("/usr/bin/dot", "dot", "-Tsvg", "temp.dot", "-o", "graph.svg", NULL);        
        std::cerr<< "dot exec error: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    wait(&status);
    if (status != 1) {
        execl("/usr/bin/eog", "eog", "graph.svg", NULL);
        std::cerr<< "eog exec error: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

I get this result:

```
Program stderr

dot exec error: No such file or directory
eog exec error: No such file or directory
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/Kh66G3j3W

Comment: He calls external programs. So if these programs are not installed on your machine or are not located at the same place, your own program will fail. However, providing `errno` and `strerror()` is indeed the first step to a successful debugging.

Comment: Any program will fail if you don't have the required libraries installed.